# @ManyToOne retrieve objects that contain a partial key using @JoinColumnOrFormula

Tags: hibernate

I'm having trouble using @JoinColumnOrFormula to retrieve specific data using a part of a key.
Let's try to explain the context.

There are two tables in the database that don't have dependency each other.

Here are the definition of those tables:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table_A")
    @IdClass(TableAPK.class)
    public class TableA {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tableA_key")
        private String key;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tableA_product")
        private String product;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tableA_territory")
        private String territory;

        @Column(name = "tableA_description")
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = TableB.class)
        private List listTableB;

        // getter/setter
    }
```

```
    @IdClass(TableAPK.class)
    public class TableAPK implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6343683597717600643L;

        private String key;

        private String product;

        private String territory;

        // getter/setter
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table_B")
    @IdClass(TableBPK.class)
    public class TableB {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tableB_key")
        private String key;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tableB_product")
        private String product;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tableB_region")
        private String region;

        @Column(name = "tableB_description")
        private String description;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = TableA.class)
        @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
          @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "tableB_key", referencedColumnName = "tableA_key", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)),
          @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "tableB_product", referencedColumnName = "tableA_product", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)),
          @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "????", referencedColumnName = "????"))
        })
        private TableA tableA;

        // getter/setter
    }
```

```
    @IdClass(TableBPK.class)
    public class TableBPK implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6343683597717600643L;

        private String key;

        private String product;

        private String region;

        // getter/setter
    }
```

As you can see TableAPK and TableBPK the primary keys are not composed by the same attributes.

```
    List listElements = em.createQuery("FROM TableA WHERE key = :key ORDER BY territory", TableA.class).setParameter("key", key).getResultList();
```

This query should returns a list TableA objects according to the key provided. Each TableA has a list of TableB which match key, product and region that is part of the key.

The key is a string that looks like this "territory_region_product_xxxx"

How can I retrieve the list of TableB that will contain 'table_B.tableB_region' in 'table_A.tableA_key'?

For instance table_A.tableA_key has
"territoryA_regionA_productA_xxxx"
"territoryA_regionA_productA_xxxx"
"territoryA_regionB_productA_xxxx"
"territoryA_regionB_productA_xxxx"

and table_B.tableB_region has
"regionA"

In this case how can I get the two first row?

How can I implement this using @JoinFormula?

Is @JoinColumnsOrFormulas a good solution in this case?

Any advice is welcome.